# How to vary the interarrival rates based on agent type in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am working on a model, where I want to vary the interarrival rates of agents based on parameter Type.

I have a parameter Type of Option List containing type2 and type7.

I tried to change the arrival rates with agent.Type == type2 ? (triangular(1,2,3)) : 50 but this is not working.

[image]

Comment: if you are talking about the source, you need to have 2 sources if you want different rates... each source will generate its own agent type

Comment: Suppose, I have 1 product with three variants type1, type2, and type3. Now I want different arrival rates for the variant products. e.g type 1 --- exponential(2) days, type3 --- exponential(3) days, and type2---exponential(1) days

I dont want to use different source blocks, as it will generate all three variants but I will only be able to set only one arrival rates.

Comment: still need 3 sources, if you don't want to use 3 sources, you will need to generate the agents by code and take them to an enter block, but then you will need 3 events

Comment: how come you say you want to set ONE arrival rate and 3 arrival rates at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a source can only contain one unique arrival rate, you can change the arrival rate during the simulation run with the function set_rate(), but you cannot have multiple arrival rates in a single source.

In order to have multiple rates, you will be forced to have multiple sources... you can use population of sources, but it's conceptually not different.

Another option is to have multiple events with multiple rates and use 1 enter block to generate your agents, in each event you will need to do

```
MyAgent m=add_myAgents(type);
enter.take(m);
```